# Other divs moves upward and goes not when image is loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple html

```
<div>
<div>Title</div>
<div><img src="" style="height:147px;" src="...." /></div>
<div>Description </div>

</div>
```

while loading page it is showig  title and description and when image is completly loaded, html is fine.

I want poistion of other div remains same while loading page.

Edit: One thing i forget to mention that html is coming through Ajax request

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give height to parent `div` containing image. It will create a boundary for the image. i.e.

```
<div style="height:147px;"><img src="" src="...." /></div>
```

Give dimensions of image as `width` and `height` (recommended).

Because by nature `div` is a block element so it has `height:auto` as default. Multimedia content like images loads a bit later than rest of `Html DOM`. So you are experiencing little delay.

Comment: One thing i forget to mention that html is coming through Ajax request